# How do you calculate the peak current of an electric motor?

Tags: current, brushless-dc-motor

I'm designing a BLDC motor and have a required constant load torque to figure out the winding size required, but I also want to know what peak torque/current it can output for a few seconds. What is the limiting factor of peak current?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum current in a permanent magnet motor is governed by two things, which are in order of importance ...

a) demagnetisation of the permanent magnets

b) heating

*Demagnetisation* will kill your motor in an instant, if the current goes over this limit at all, it's game over. Fortunately, it takes a rather large current to do it. Unless the manufacturer specifies it directly, it can be rather difficult / impossible to infer from the other specifications. You can assume it's above the peak rated current, but by what safety factor, 2x, 5x, 10x ? If it's not in the data sheet, one way is to contact the manufacturer, another is to test a motor, with the expectation of destroying it. After demagnetisation, the Kt will be lower, zero or even reversed, a quick measurement of output torque will detect this.

*Heating* is a bit more tractable, but still needs some guesswork. The limitation is the temperature of the windings, as the insulation is good only up to a certain temperature. Fortunately it's easy to estimate the temperature of the windings by measuring their resistance, copper has a relatively large 10% change in resistance for every 25C increase in temperature. Unfortunately, the specs probably do not tell you what the limiting temperature on the windings is. Best is to play safe and assume (say) 80C for the max temperature, \$t_{max}\$

The method is to measure the approximate \$I^2t_{max}\$ of the windings. Measure the starting temperature \$t_{initial}\$. Apply a 10 second pulse (short enough to be roughly adiabatic, long enough to be useful) of rated current, and estimate the temperature rise from the change in resistance. The \$I^2t\$ you have just applied, \$I^2t_{test}\$, is 10*Irated*Irated. The maximum \$I^2t\$ you can apply safely, \$I^2t_{max}\$, is $$I^2t_{max}=\frac{t_{max}-t_{initial}}{ temperature rise}I^2t_{test}$$

The maximum you can apply on thermal grounds is *any* current I, as long as the application time is less than $$\frac{I^2t_{max}}{I^2}$$ in a single pulse, starting with a cold motor. If you apply multiple pulses, then you must use less current, to keep the temperature down.

Comment: After demagnetisation' won't Kv (rpm/V) be higher? (you need to spin faster to generate the back EMF ... aka "field reduction" in wound field motors)

Answer (score 1):

Staying short of the physical limits of the motor as in Neil's answer - i.e. operating within its ratings - the simple answer is given by dividing its rated voltage by its winding resistance. This is the stall current.

I(stall) = V(nominal) / R(winding)

You'd like to think that the motor designers have accounted for the possibility of demagnetisation and set the rated voltage such that the stall current won't cause demagnetisation - but it's something to bear in mind if you're operating a BLDC motor beyond its nominal voltage (along with bearing speeds, centrifugal forces, and fragmentation if you exceed its material strength). If you're designing your own motor it's definitely one of the considerations.

However they cannot always make a motor safe for continuous operation at stall current - so it's up to you to limit the duration of stall (or heavily loaded) operation, either by measuring the motor current or its temperature.

Comment: Stall current, or more usually starting current, is a valid concept for conventional brushed PM motors, but with a BLDC drive being entirely through an ESC, it's rather more down to the programming of the ESC. Rereading the OP, it sounds like he's messing with the motor design, rather than just buying one?

Comment: @Neil_UK True, you can limit stall current in the controller, and many do (as a means of soft-starting the motor). But you can revise the statement (and I possibly should) to say that V/R provides an upper bound on stall current. Of course, either designing your own motor, or rewinding a commercial one, you can choose R by varying the number of turns (which also varies Kv and Kt) then selecting the largest wire gauge that will fit the winding space.